# xml parsing / querying performance question for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, caching, xml-serialization

I have to port a smaller windows forms application (product configurator) to an asp.net app which will be used on a large company's website, demand should be moderate because it's for a specialized product line.

I don't have access to a database and using XML is a requirement from their web developers.

There are roughly 30 different products with roughly 300 different possible configurations stored in the xml files, and linked questions / answers that lead to a product recommendation. Also some production options. The app is available in 6 languages.

How would you solve the 'data access' layer, if you could call it this way? I thought of  reading / deserializing the xml files into their objects and store them in asp.net's cache if they're not there already and then read from the cache on subsequent requests. But that would mean all objects live in the memory all day and night.

Is that even necessary, or smart, performance wise? As I said before, the app is not that big, the xml files not that large. Could I just create some Repository class that reads the xml files whenever an object is requested (ie. 'Product Details', or 'Next question') and returns it that way, and drive memory consumption down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole approach seems to be sticking to a single server. First consider if this is appropriate as you mentioned a "large company's website", that sets a red flag for me. If you need the site to scale, you will end up having more than a single server, which prevents considering a simple local file.

If you are constrained to using that, analyze what data is more appropriate to keep in cache (does not change often, its long lived, the same info is requested different times).  Try to keep the cached stuff separated from the non cached, which will reduce the amount of amount of info in the more dynamic files. If you expect big amounts of information, consider splitting the files with something appropriate to your domain.

Comment: i'd love to use a database, but it's the sysadmins of the company that prevent me from doing it :/

Comment: and somehow, to me, the possibility of multiple servers seems to prevent me from using caching efficiently, but not from the file approach...

Answer (score 0):

I use Cache whenever I can. I cache objects upon their first request. If memory is of any concern, I set expiration policy. And whether it is or not, when short on memory, the framework will unload the cache anyway.

Since it is per application and not per user, it makes sense to have it, especially if the relative footprint is small.

If you have to expand to multiple servers later, you can access the same file over the network or modify DA layer to retrieve data by any other means (services, DB, etc). The caching code will stay the same and performance will be virtually unaffected.

If you set dependency, objects will always stay current.

I'm for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the cache, and setting an appropriate expiration policy as advised by others is a sound approach. I'd suggest you look at using LINQ to XML as the basis for your data access code as it is so much easier to use than traditional methods of querying XML. You can find a decent introduction [here](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx).